# Changing the column sorted by causes rows to be skipped or duplicated in stored procedure

Tags: sorting, stored-procedures, pagination, sql-server-2008-r2

In the process of debugging another process I discovered that the stored procedure I was pulling data from exhibited some odd behavior. If I sort on the column `project` every single row is returned no problem but if I sort on the column `pjt_entity` then some columns appear to be dropped and others are duplicated but I can't figure out why or how to stop it as I have to sort on the bad column.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[WSL_TaskSearchByDate]
    @page int,
    @size int,
    @sort nvarchar(200),
    @parm1 nvarchar(50) --Search Date
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @STMT nvarchar(MAX),
        @lBound int,
        @uBound int

IF (@sort = '')
BEGIN
    SET @sort = 'Task';
END

IF (@page = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @STMT =
        'SELECT pjt_entity AS Task,
                pjt_entity_desc AS Description,
                status_gl AS Status,
                project AS ParentProject
        FROM dbo.PJPENT WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE (crtd_datetime >= ''' + @parm1 + ''' AND project != '''')
        OR (lupd_datetime >= ''' + @parm1 + ''' AND project != '''');';         
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF (@page < 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @page = 1;
    END

    IF (@size < 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @size = 1;
    END

    SET @lBound = (@page - 1) * @size;
    SET @uBound = @page * @size + 1;

    SET @STMT =
        'WITH PagingCTE AS
         (
            SELECT  TOP(' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @uBound - 1) + ')
                    pjt_entity,
                    pjt_entity_desc,
                    status_gl,
                    project,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER
                    (
                        ORDER BY ' + @sort + '
                    ) AS row
            FROM dbo.PJPENT WITH (NOLOCK)
            WHERE (crtd_datetime >= ''' + @parm1 + ''' AND project != '''')
            OR (lupd_datetime >= ''' + @parm1 + ''' AND project != '''')
        )
        SELECT  pjt_entity AS Task,
                pjt_entity_desc AS Description,
                status_gl AS Status,
                project AS ParentProject
        FROM PagingCTE
        WHERE row > ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @lBound) + '
        AND row < ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @uBound) + '
        ORDER BY row';
END

EXEC sp_executesql @STMT, N'@page int, @size int, @sort nvarchar(200), @param1 nvarchar(12)', @page, @size, @sort, @parm1;
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PJPENT]
(
    [contract_type] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [crtd_datetime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [crtd_prog] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [crtd_user] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [end_date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [fips_num] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [labor_class_cd] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [lupd_datetime] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [lupd_prog] [char](8) NOT NULL,
    [lupd_user] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [manager1] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [MSPData] [char](50) NOT NULL,
    [MSPInterface] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [MSPSync] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [MSPTask_UID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [noteid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [opportunityProduct] [char](36) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id01] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id02] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id03] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id04] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id05] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id06] [float] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id07] [float] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id08] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id09] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id10] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id31] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id32] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id33] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id34] [char](20) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id35] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id36] [char](10) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id37] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [pe_id38] [float] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id39] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [pe_id40] [int] NOT NULL,
    [pjt_entity] [char](32) NOT NULL,
    [pjt_entity_desc] [char](60) NOT NULL,
    [project] [char](16) NOT NULL,
    [start_date] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [status_08] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_09] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_10] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_11] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_12] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_13] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_14] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_15] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_16] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_17] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_18] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_19] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_20] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_ap] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_ar] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_gl] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_in] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_lb] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_pa] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [status_po] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [user1] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [user2] [char](30) NOT NULL,
    [user3] [float] NOT NULL,
    [user4] [float] NOT NULL,
    [tstamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [pjpent0] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([project] ASC, [pjt_entity] ASC)
          WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Code used to test and find my results:

```
DECLARE @totalRows int,
        @page int,
        @testCount int;

SET @totalRows = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.PJPENT WHERE project != '');
SET @page = 0;
SET @testCount = 0;

WHILE (@testCount < @totalRows)
BEGIN
    SET @page = (@page + 1);
    SET @testCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TaskTestTemp)

    INSERT INTO #TaskTestTemp
    --EXEC dbo.WSL_TaskSearchByDate @page, 110, 'project', '1990-01-01'; --All counts = 1
    EXEC dbo.WSL_TaskSearchByDate @page, 110, 'pjt_entity', '1990-01-01'; --Counts vary from 1 to 6
END

SELECT  Task,
        ParentProject,
        COUNT(*) AS rawCount
FROM #TaskTestTemp
GROUP BY Task, ParentProject
ORDER BY rawCount DESC;

DROP TABLE #TaskTestTemp
```

I can not do anything about the table definition as it is a Microsoft Dynamics table so I have no control over it, I can alter the stored procedure as it is one I built based off the existing ones in Dynamics. What might be causing this odd problem of mine and what would be a good solution to preventing it?

Comment: If you want *deterministic* ordering (most people do, even when they don't say so), it's important for you to ensure enough columns are specified in any `ORDER BY` clause such that *every* row has distinct values for those columns. Without doing so, any ordering can be *arbitrary* (within the bounds required by the columns you **have** specified).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am not sure what you mean. Each task belongs to a project so if I specify the project column that does not put a unique value in that column for each row but it has no problems while if I specify pjt_entity the problem exists even though there is not unique value.

Comment: Correction - "if I specify the project column ... it has no **apparent** problems" (My emphasis). Just because you've not observed any problems in your limited testing does not mean that they're not lurking just below the surface. There is *one* way to obtain *guaranteed* behaviour from the system with regards to ordering, and that's (as I previously said) ensuring that you specify enough expressions in the `ORDER BY` clause. Usually you can specify any custom sorting and *then* the PK columns to obtain that guarantee.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever So if I understand you right your saying just to increase the amount of columns in the sort parameter and that even though I don't have a problem on sorting by project right now as the table grows the probably of this problem creeping up increases? If so how can I test to make sure that added columns don't give me a false positive as well?

Comment: Yes. You're currently programming by *coincidence*, by assuming that the behaviour you're *observing* is somehow guaranteed. By extending the set of columns in your `ORDER BY` beyond the custom sort order and also including a set of columns that form a *key*, you're insuring that you're programming by *guarantee*. The most obvious key to use is the PK.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever If you want to write that up in an answer then I can accept it